# Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: Found installation canary

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

I am new to civicrm and I have been recommended by a friend to try it out for my website. But before I do that I would like to try it our on my laptop via xampp.

I installed wordpress and then civicrm everything seemed to have went through but now when I click on civicrm it gives me this error.

***[0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\Civi\Core\InstallationCanary.php on line 53***

Could someone please guide me on how to solve this.

Tanmaya

Comment: Sorry for posting this as an answer it should be a comment but since I'm new the system will not allow me to comment and I did not want to open a duplicate question. I have this same problem. Installed xampp-win32-7.0.9-1-VC14-installer followed by bitnami-wordpress-4.6.1-3-module-windows-installer and finally civicrm-4.7.12-wordpress. Followed the installation instructions at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress - completed without error. Completed the install script after activating the wordpress plugin without errors. When selecting the CiviCRM

Answer (score 1):

@Mike 
The name of your XAMPP installer suggests that you are testing with PHP 7. That is bleeding edge technology for CiviCrm. According to [CRM-17789](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789) thats supported for the first time in CiviCrm version 4.7.12. Maybe you can retry your installation using PHP 5.6.